# Wait for completion of UpdateByQuery with the elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm working with a really large dataset and I need to clean (remove) some properties of some documents, and immediately after to add such a property to other documents. Sometimes, the documents with the property being removed are the ones that I should update after. The problem is that sometimes there is a ConflictError, and I wonder how can I wait for the first query to be fully executed to later execute the second one. This is the code I'm using:

```
ubq = UpdateByQuery(using=self.es, index=self.index).update_from_dict(query1).script(source=script_remove_source)
ubq.execute()

ubq = UpdateByQuery(using=self.es, index=self.index).update_from_dict(query2).script(source=script_add_source)
ubq.execute()
```

Any idea?

In the elastic docs they mention the param [wait_for_completion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), but they don't present an example of use. And anyway, that's not the Elasticsearch DSL. I read the [DSL docs](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/update_by_query.html?highlight=UpdateByQuery) but nothing is sayd about sync or async.

What I'm doing right now is putting a sleep in between of 3 seconds... And it works, but that's completely awful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using conflict=proceed. I don't know the correct command for DSL.

Comment: how to deal with conflicts in above case?

Comment: @SurajDalvi I did it with retry_on_conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed it with retry_on_conflict:

```
es.update(
                index=index,
                doc_type=doc_type,
                id=id_str,
                body={"doc": {
                    session: state
                }},
                retry_on_conflict=5
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

`elasticsearch-dsl-py` is a high level API on top of `elasticsearch-py`.  It looks like `wait_for_completion` already defaults to true ([https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/9f4baacb7059c9fb1f949fd8e726749137408a9c/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py#L936](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/9f4baacb7059c9fb1f949fd8e726749137408a9c/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#L936)) and it looks like elasticsearch-dsl-py doesn't change that (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/601f7e9c5a708a3b6144851053e0544660bcf0a7/elasticsearch_dsl/update_by_query.py#L145).

What if you trigger a refresh?  It looks like you can forward such params to the lower level API based on the example in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/870.

Could there be another process interacting/updating records?

Comment: Thanks eemp! I had to change activities but I'm checking it this week. I'll be back to mark the answer and reply soon!

Comment: Since the `updateByQuery` API unfortunately does not support the `wait_for=wait_for` you have no guarantee that you can immediately query the data you sent. I don't think `retry_on_conflict` helps you here - you would need to manually `refresh()` the index.